# Preventing a null argument from causing a 'NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, .net, exception, null, nullreferenceexception

In my libraries I often exposes methods that take a string as a parameter. Should I always check if the string parameter is equal to `null`? Or is it OK to ignore the possibility of a `null` value that would lead to a `NullreferenceException`?

Example:

```
public static void Parse(string line)
{
     string[] splits = line.Split(' ');
}
```

In this method, `line` can be `null` which would cause `Parse` to throw a `NullreferenceException`. (Specifically, because of the attempt to invoke `Split` on a `null` value.) Should I check if `line` is `null` to prevent the exception from being thrown?

Comment: Well.. Yes. Why not?

Comment: From a more pragmatic standpoint, yes. `NullReferenceException` almost always indicates a bug right where it was thrown. If I called `Parse` and it threw `NullReferenceException`, I would assume that there's a bug in the `Parse` method. If, however, it threw `ArgumentNullException`, I would know that the bug was mine. See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/16/null-parameters-in-extension-methods/ for a related argument.

Comment: In response to the votes to close this question as opinion-based, I better-aligned the question title with the specific scenario posed by the question and voted to reopen the question. And as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38267992/1497596), Microsoft provides specific guidance for the situation posed by this question. Therefore, because this question has an answer backed by an authoritative reference, it should not be closed as opinion-based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should definitely prevent it from being thrown.

You're designing a library and exposing a library method, so your consumers shouldn't have to dive into your source to see why a perfectly preventable `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

Depending on what the code following that statement does, you either provide a default value or throw an `ArgumentNullException`:

```
line = line ?? "";
```

Or:

```
if (line == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("line");
}
```

Comment: Calling a "Parse" method with a null argument is a bug.  Never hide bugs.

Comment: @Hans regarding `?? ""` I assume? I wholeheartedly agree, though in some situations providing a default value when the input is `null` makes sense. It indeed does not if it's a single-parameter parsing method and that parameter is `null`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: disagree about library methods not throwing exceptions. That's exactly what library methods should do. Consider how XmlSerializer communicates to you when it detects illegal XML. Or how ADO.NET communicates back to you. Or how pretty much **every** third party library communicates to you. The correct statement should be, *library methods are expected to throw exceptions when invalid conditions (e.g. null args, missing args, etc etc) are encountered*.

Comment: @code4life the question is about NullReferenceException. No library should throw those.

Answer (score 1):

Your question concerns whether it is advisable to check whether a reference-type argument passed to a method is `null` before attempting to dereference it within the method.

Microsoft advises that you *should* make this check. Specifically, if you inspect your `Parse` method with the [Code Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx) tool in Visual Studio, it will issue warning [CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx). Here is the introductory text from this article:

> ## Cause
>
> An externally visible method dereferences one of its reference
>   arguments without verifying whether that argument is **null** (**Nothing** in
>   Visual Basic).
>
> ## Rule Description
>
> All reference arguments that are passed to externally visible methods
>   should be checked against **null**. If appropriate, throw a
>   [ArgumentNullException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx) when the argument is **null**.
>
> If a method can be called from an unknown assembly because it is
>   declared public or protected, you should validate all parameters of
>   the method. If the method is designed to be called only by known
>   assemblies, you should make the method internal and apply the
>   [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to the assembly that contains
>   the method.
>
> ## How to Fix Violations
>
> To fix a violation of this rule, validate each reference argument
>   against **null**.
>
> ## When to Suppress Warnings
>
> You can suppress a warning from this rule if you are sure that the
>   dereferenced parameter has been validated by another method call in
>   the function.

See the second code example in the article for CA1062 for a scenario where using a private method to validate an argument is helpful (and maybe even essential).